# Is it possible to update Images on webpage using XPM ? Images published to file system not DB

Tags: experience-manager, image

Will it be feasible to update Images also on webpage using XPM ? We are publishing Images on file system not DB.  Using DD4T 2.0 (Java) , Tridion 2013 SP1 with Tomcat 7.0

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to update images through XPM. Just make sure you have proper XPM tag around images.

You can consider images as you referenced them in CME, same way XPM will work. You can change image very easily.

File system deployment is on content delivery side which will happen when you finish editing in XPM. On click on finish editing in XPM, the changes for images will be published to file system.